# IIS ftp server not responding to get file size

Tags: iis, ftp

I have an external board that is connected to my IIS ftp server.

I am running the external board code, and it downloads SUCCESSFULLY a file from my ftp server.

inside this file there is another file name in the root ftp folder that the board is trying to get it's file size and fail (from what i see in the log).

When I am doing the same operation with the same files over the Board's manufacturers ftp server - the operation succeeded.

Do i need to do something special in order to allow getting the file size in my ftp server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate your ftp site on left pane. Find "ftp directory browsing" on right pane. Set UNIX instead of MS-DOS (default). Alternatively edit configuration manually https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/ftpserver/directorybrowse